# Scrapy not returning any results

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to build a Scrapy spider to retrieve content from a German news site. However I do not get any responses. This is a minimal version of my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ZeitSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Zeit Online'
    allowed_domains = ['zeit.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.zeit.de']

    def parse(self,response):
        self.logger.info('A response from %s just arrived!', response.url)
```

So my understanding is that this minimal example spider crawls exactly the start url and calls the `parse` function on it, which then should give a log entry. But nothing happens. This is the log from calling `scrapy crawl`:

```
2021-01-07 08:34:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: newsscraper)
2021-01-07 08:34:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) - [GCC 8.4.0], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018), cryptography 2.1.4, Platform Linux-4.15.0-128-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2021-01-07 08:34:56 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
```

Is something missing in my code? Or is this rather some other problem? How would I check this?

Comment: Never mind.  I see you have to call a scrapy program with scrapy.  The python doesn't run by itself.

Comment: Replace `CrawlSpider` with `Spider`.